# Installed BLTouch - what do I need to tell Cura? Just G29, or more to it?

Tags: creality-ender-3, marlin, ultimaker-cura, bed-leveling, bltouch

I added a BLTouch to my Ender3v2.  Yay!  But my first layer is still as sketchy as it's ever been.
I've got the firmware updated, and I can see the auto-level process take place at the beginning of my print - I can watch the probe measure a 5x5 grid.

I updated the start G-code in Cura to do a `G29` immediately after the `G28`, and I do see the auto-level sequence after homing at the beginning of all my prints, so things are happening.  But it doesn't seem like the auto-level has improved anything.  I've got single-layer test patterns that look OK on one part of the bed and look like the nozzle's crushed into the bed on another part.

Most of the web help I've found implies that all I need to do is insert `G29` in the start sequence.

But other places talk about saving the auto-level settings to the EEPROM, `M500`/`M501`; do I need to do that if I'm running a new auto-level immediately before every print?

And I've just this evening run across the `M420` command, which looks awfully relevant; do I need to add an `M420 S1` command to *use* the auto-level mesh I just found with `G29`?

Comment: Hi and welcome to 3D printing.SE! SE websites are driven by questions and answers, your question contains multiple questions which makes it more difficult to answer as there are multiple answers. Please read the [help] section, accessible through the button with the question mark at the top right menu and read [ask]. Please split up your question by adding the other questions in a separate question! E.g. the question on the sending of commands is answered [here](/10573). Please remove that from the question. The rest of the questions are related to G29. Thanks!